# Google MAPs api v2 AJAX not working

Tags: google-maps

My code is not working what is going wrong I can't understand...my code is:

```
/* =================Call.php========================*/
<?php
/* Include settings My mysql database */
include ("config.php");
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
     <title>GG-Tracker (GSM and GPS location combined)</title>
     <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=myAPIKey&sensor=true" type="text/javascript"></script>

<?php

echo "
   <script type=\"text/javascript\">
    var map;
   function load() {
     if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
       var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById(\"map\"));
   downloadUrl(\"phpsqlajax_genxml.php\", function(data) {
   var xml = data.responseXML;
   var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName(\"marker
\");
   for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
     var lat = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute(\"lat\"));
     var lon = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute(\"lon\"));
     var html = \"<b>\" +  \"</b> <br/>\" ;
     var marker = new GMarker(new GLatLng(lat, lon));
     map.addOverlay(marker);
     }
   }
 }
}
function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
     {
     request=new XMLHttpRequest();
     }
   else
     {
     request=new ActiveXObject(\"Microsoft.XMLHTTP\");
     }
  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (request.readyState == 4) {
     request.onreadystatechange = doNothing();
     callback(request, request.status);
   }
  };
   request.open(\"GET\", url, true);
   request.send();
  }

 function doNothing() {}
  </script>
  ";
 ?>
 </head>
 <body onload="load()" onunload="GUnload()">
 <center>
  <div id="map" style="width: 800px; height: 600px"></div>
  </body>
  </html>
 /* End of =============Call.php===============*/
```

My phpsqlajax_genxml.php for genrating XML is:

```
 /* Start of ===========phpsqlajax_genxml.php=============== */
 <?php
 require("phpsqlajax_dbinfo.php");
 $dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
 $node = $dom->createElement("markers");
 $parnode = $dom->appendChild($node);
 $connection=mysql_connect ($dbhost, $username, $password);
 if (!$connection) {
 die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
 }
 $db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
 if (!$db_selected) {
 die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
 }
// Select all the rows in the markers table
$query = "SELECT * FROM markers";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
 }
header("Content-type: text/xml");
// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
$node = $dom->createElement("marker");
$newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
$newnode->setAttribute("tid",$row['TID']);
$newnode->setAttribute("devid",$row['DevID']);
$newnode->setAttribute("ldate",$row['LDate']);
$newnode->setAttribute("ltime",$row['LTime']);
$newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['Lat']);
$newnode->setAttribute("lon", $row['Lon']);
$newnode->setAttribute("speed", $row['Speed']);
}
echo $dom->saveXML();
?>
/*=========End of=============phpsqlajax_genxml.php*/
```

My Database information file is: phpsqlajax_dbinfo.php

```
/*=========Start of=== phpsqlajax_dbinfo.php============*/

<?php
$dbhost = "localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$database="mygps";
$gmaps = "AIzaSyCRf9drwSYjBSeKpvSkEHFKqX_yBpq-Tkk";
?>

/*===========End of phpsqlajax_dbinfo.php==============*/
```

the above three files cant work.

If I run only phpsqlajax_genxml.php file to generate XML it is working
I can generate XML but it cannot downloaded through JAVA - I think AJAX call is not
working....

What to do auto reload marker from MySQL on some time interval without
reloading whole page like Live Tracking.....

Please Help Me My above code is not working

Thanks for Reading
Pradip

Answer (score 0):

The V2 API is deprecated and you should migrate to V3 of the API.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason for using php-echo to output  HTML-source?

However, if the code above is really what you actually use, you have a problem here:

```
var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName(\"marker
\");
```

the line-break will break your script, remove it.